# ActiveMQ / Camel Behavior when a message expires while being processed

Tags: jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am trying to understand the behavior when a message expires while it is being processed. I have the following flow setup in my test program.

queue.start -> sleepProcessor -> queue.end

The sleepProcessor takes the message from queue.start and sleeps for 5 seconds. I send a message to queue.start with a JMSExpiration of 1 second from System.currentTimeMillis(). I have setup dead letter queues for each queue named DLQ.queue.start and DLQ.queue.end.

The behavior I see is that 1 message ends up in DLQ.queue.start and another message ends up in DLQ.queue.end. 
How does 1 message become 2?

The test program can be found here with source

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=04225732819763428273

I have included a maven pom.xml and the test program can be run with the following command

mvn camel:run

OS: Linux 3.5.0 (Mint 14)

JVM: 1.6

ActiveMQ: 5.7.0

Camel: 2.8.2

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the discussion, I think it is useful to show all the important parts of your code.

Your route looks as follows:

```
from("jms:queue.start")
    .transacted()
    .process(sleepProcessor)
    .to("jms:queue.end");
```

The headers is set as follows:

```
final Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
final long expiration = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000;  // <-- start time plus 1 second!
headers.put("JMSExpiration", expiration);
```

Finally, the processing is started as follows:

```
final ProducerTemplate template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
template.sendBodyAndHeaders("jms:queue.start", "Test message", headers);
```

What happend during the processing:

- The route is started and the message is sent to `jms:queue.start` with expiration time set to 1 second
- The `jms:queue.start` route receives the messages and the `sleepProcessor` waits 5 seconds. Note, that no acknowledgment is sent to the JMS broker yet (a message is only acknowledged at the end of the Camel route). During this time, the message is expired and we see the *first* log produced by the DLQ processor.
- Afterwards, the message is put to `jms:queue.end`. The message header `JMSExpriation` indicates, that the message is expired (> start time plus 5 seconds), and the message is expired right away, and we see the *second* log produced by the DLQ processor looking as the message is duplicated.

Conclusion:

- The route `jms:queue.start` is not cancelled even if the JMS message is expired during the processing. Of course, the reason for this is that it is just not possible/allowed for the JMS broker to cancel an ongoing message consumpation. We have to live with that and react accordingly in the DLQ processors.